# Best way to display XML in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to display a XML-File which I read with MSXML `Getxml()` into a CString
I tried to display the string in a CListBox, but my CListBox will display it like:
[image: CListBox]

but I would like to have real line breaks instead of this squares!

but the XML i read is formatted well with CR/LF:
[image: XML]

May CListBox isn't the right Method to display a XML?
Or do i have to replace CR/LF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a web-browser control and you can use this, if you need nice formatting of your XML. Please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I accepted your answer because this control has a nice formatting and works fine for me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think is better to use a multiline [CEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), or a [RichEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2hkhzhe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: yeah, looks better than to split the whole XML to add each line... will test it tomorrow